# AS/400 View not displaying correctly in Crystal Reports

Tags: ibm-midrange, crystal-reports-xi

I finally got Views that are created on AS/400 to show up in Crystal Reports. It may have been a space issue.  We added disk.

The issue now is when looking at the data, if you look at the view on AS/400 you will see normal data, as here:

```
                               Part#
PCK    22      01      A01     CRCUP7                       33.00    CRW                                   .00  
PCK    22      01      A02     CRCUP9-L                     32.00    CRW                                   .00  
PCK    22      01      A03     CRCUP7-L                     48.00    CRW                                   .00  
PCK    22      01      B01     SWRS2                       682.00    CRW                                   .00  
PCK    22      01      B02     SWRS2-G                     358.00    CRW                                   .00  
PCK                            -                                 -   -                                     .00  
PCK    22      01      C01     SWRS-G                    3,391.00    CRW                                   .00  
PCK    22      01      C02     SWRS                        408.00    CRW                                   .00  
PCK    22      01      C03     HWCR5-G                     735.00    CRW                                   .00
```

However, when I access this dynamic view in the Crystal Report, I have this for part#
C1C1C160D7D3C4D4F5404040404040 and alot of 40's and 404040404040

WHy would this be happening?

Comment: You are looking at the hex values for EBCDIC data.  x'40' is a space.  Try JamesA's solution.

Comment: Sidebar note:  IBM has not shipped an AS/400 since 2000. The product line has been replaced or rebranded several times since then. If your system is at all recent, you are most likely using a Power System, running "IBM i" as the OS, and the database is now called "DB2 for i".  Some people persist in clinging to the old names, but they shouldn't call the box on your desk an IBM PC/XT either.

Comment: thanks for your help and good point I will change the language going forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CCSID is set to 65535 (hex).

Add the `Force Translate=0` property to your connection string.

Comment: Or have the IBM system administrator set the IBM i user profile to the proper CCSID.  In the US that would be 37.  Or, have the IBM system administrator change the system value QCCSID to the proper value for the language the system uses.

Comment: I dont see Force translate in Crystal Reports also.

Comment: @PinchasK You would add it to the connection string for the database connection in Crystal Reports.  For example: `Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=<system>;Force Translate=0`.

Comment: I think this is sort of a known issue with crystal, there are some relatively simple formulas to convert. THe string you gave, I am not using this sort of string but according to other people with same issue I can run a simple formula on those columns.

Comment: I found out the issue. On Iseries Access for Windows, There is a box for convert binary data to text it was unchecked so I checked it and the data is now NOT hex in the Crystal Reports. This wont' affect the data on the IBM i ?

Comment: @PinchasK That probably sets the same parameter.  It has no effect on the actual data in the table.